# grid view selected row data

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

i am getting the data from gridview on rowcommand event by the following code

```
protected void GridView2_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "editproject")
    {
        string rowindex = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        int index = int.Parse(rowindex);
        GridViewRow row = GridView2.Rows[index];
        Label6.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
    }
}
```

but it would give only the data of the field that is visible in gridview row .how can i get the field that is not visible but bound to the gridview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the value that you set to invisible because these were not rendered at the client side and can't be grabbed on the server side.

Alternatively you can store the value in hidden field and then you can get it from hidden field.

Comment: so there is no way to get the value.

Comment: one way is i can get the datakeyvalue of the selected row and query the database using the linq query and get the values.i thought there would be simpler method

Comment: @saurabh `DataKeys` can hold multiple values, you may choose to add the column there

Comment: You may save the values in hidden field and that you can access.

Comment: @V4vendetta i got the datakey of the selected row by string projecid = GridView2.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();

Answer (score 1):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{   
    MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString ());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can,t get the invisible bound elements but you can get the value from data source .For example you save data in data table which assigned to grid .Store this data table in view-state and on row command get data-key of that row and retrieved value through data table

Answer (score 0):

You can get a command-like button which is invisible in the gridview, just look at this:---
False visibility of button requires you to have changed the property `EnableEventValidation="False"` on the page directive in `default.aspx`

```
private void grd_bind()
{
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select* from tbbook", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        LinkButton lk = (LinkButton)(e.Row.Cells[5].Controls[0]);
        e.Row.Attributes["Onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(lk, "");
    }
}

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
    TextBox2.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    TextBox3.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
    TextBox4.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
    TextBox5.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text;
}
```

then in the `default.aspx` page, set `EnableEventValidation`

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" EnableEventValidation="false" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>
```